# No files with prefix com.apple.security in Library?

Tags: preferences

I have been having issues with Safari not showing https sites.  The best solution I have found googling around seems to be to delete either `com.apple.security.plist` or `com.apple.security.revocation.plist`, but in `Library/Preferences` I have no mention of any `com.apple.security` file.

I have not found anything that seems applicable to this exact problem.  Could anyone shed light on why this file might be missing, and/or how to restore it?

I have tried the following

- Resetting Safari
- Rebooting
- Keychain first aid, no errors
- Executing "ls -l ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.*.plist";which showed no file in results.

Answer (score 1):

On my iMac the `com.apple.security.plist` is located in the `Preferences` folder in the `Local Domain`:

```
    /Library/Preferences
```

but you were looking in the `Preferences` folder in the `User Domain`:

```
    ~/Library/Preferences   (aka: /Users/[username]/Library Preferences)
```

There was no `com.apple.security.revocation.plist` file in any of the  Preferences folders on my iMac. If one did exist I'd expect it to be in the same Preferences folder as the above `plist` file.

Check your `/Library/Preferences` folder for either or both of those `plist` files.

If you aren't familiar with domains in OS X and how they affect the use of files then you can see Apple's documentation for an overview: [About the OS X File System](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW15)